# Why doesn't Hadoop respect 'spark.hadoop.fs' properties set in pyspark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3, properties, configuration

There are three properties in my `spark-defaults.conf` that I want to be able to set dynamically:

- `spark.driver.maxResultSize`
- `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key`
- `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key`

Here's my attempt to do so:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = (SparkConf()
        .setMaster(spark_master)
        .setAppName(app_name)
        .set('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '5g')
        .set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key', '<access>')\
        .set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key', '<secret>)
        )

spark = SparkSession.builder.\
    config(conf=conf).\
    getOrCreate()

print(spark.conf.get('spark.driver.maxResultSize'))
print(spark.conf.get('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key'))
print(spark.conf.get('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key'))

spark.stop()
```

Here's the output I get:

```
5g
<access>
<secret>
```

However when I try to read a csv file on S3 using this configuration, I get a permissions denied error.

If I set the credentials via environment variables, I am able to read the file.

Why doesn't Hadoop respect the credentials specified this way?

Update:

I am aware of other Q&As relating to setting Hadoop properties in pyspark.

Here I am trying to record for posterity how you can be fooled into thinking that you can set them dynamically via `spark.hadoop.*`, since that is the name you use to set these properties in `spark-defaults.conf`, and since you don't get an error directly when you try to set them this way.

Many sites tell you to "set the `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key` property", but don't specify that this only the case if you set it statically in `spark-defaults.conf` and not dynamically in `pyspark`.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that you can't specify Hadoop properties via:

`spark.conf.set('spark.hadoop.<property>', <value>)`

but you must instead use:

`spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('<property>', <value>)`

I believe you can only use `spark.conf.set()` for the properties listed on the [Spark Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) page.

Comment: sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set(key,value)  

Check the integration test for http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/combineparquetfileinputformat/

Comment: @KrazyGautam – this is for `pyspark` not scala/java.

Comment: You can actually set the hadoop related properties via spark conf. 
At least in 2.2.1 version that I tested in my scala code. 
So it goes like this:  
`SparkSession.builder()
          .master("local[*]")
          .appName(s"theApplicationName")
          .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1)
          .config("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", "file:///")
          .getOrCreate() `

Comment: @MinnieShi – this is for pyspark, not scala.

Comment: @proinsias Thanks but I couldn't set `fs.defaultFS`. It gives me error `An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get.
: java.lang.NullPointerException`. Is it because it's unsupported property which is not suggested in the list of Spark Configuration page?