# How to access azure block file system (abfss) from a standalone spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a need to use a standalone spark cluster (2.4.7) with Hadoop 3.2 and I am trying to access the ADLS Gen2 storage through pyspark.

I've added a shared key to my core-site.xml and I can *ls* the storage account like so:

```
hadoop fs -ls abfss://<container>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/
```

But when I try to read a json file in pyspark (using the shell) like so:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<<storageaccount>>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<<key>>")

spark.read.option("multiLine", True).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("abfss://<container>@<storageaccount>.dfs.core.windows.net/example.json").show()
```

I get the following error:

```
WARN streaming.FileStreamSink: Error while looking for metadata directory.
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o103.json.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: abfss
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:561)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:559)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:559)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:242)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:411)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)WARN: command not found
```

I have also configured the HADOOP lib paths for `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH` to point to `$(hadoop classpath)` and copied over the `hadoop-azure` jar to the `hadoop/common` folder. But still unable to access abfss via pyspark.

What could I be missing here?

Also tried answers [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727064/why-doesnt-hadoop-respect-spark-hadoop-fs-properties-set-in-pyspark)

Comment: Could you please tell me how you run the code?

Comment: @JimXu using pyspark shell

Comment: Is that you install spark, enter pyspark in the command-line tool  then run the code?

Comment: @JimXu Correct, on the command line ... testing to see if spark picks up hadoop key config & the abfs drivers

Answer (score 1):

This article helps you to [DIY: Apache Spark and ADLS Gen 2 support](https://deep.data.blog/2019/07/12/diy-apache-spark-and-adls-gen-2-support/), make sure you have followed all the necessary steps to successfully configure ADLS gen2 on Apache Spark.

Comment: Any hadoop free version of spark should work, for me though, this is what worked:
Hadoop 3.2.1 (wildfly issues with 3.2.0) with spark 2.4.7. I also needed to copy over apache-hive jars (scala 2.11) for Livy to work with this setup